# How can I talk to my Battle.net Real ID friends?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So I'm playing wow again.

The last time I played (a year or so ago or so) I added a few peoples as my [Real ID](http://us.battle.net/en/realid/) Friends. Now that I'm back I'm clicking around the wow GUI and I can't figure out how to send them a message.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't played WoW for a few months, but your RealID Friends should show up at the top of your friends list when you open the Social panel, on the friends tab.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by opening your friends list, they should show up there. You can right click them to send a message.

There is also an icon on the top right of the chat window what will show your friends list.